# How to write MySQL query in CakePHP format?

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.0

i have faced in a problem.
Can you please write this query in cakephp format

**Table**

```
id   from_id  to_id  is_active  message
---  -------  -----  ---------  -------
 1     1        8       1       Hello
 2     8        1       1       Yes
 3     1        8       1       How are you?
 4     1        8       1       Are you with me?
```

**Code :**

```
<?php
    $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE (from_id='8' OR  to_id='1') AND (from_id='1' OR  to_id='8') AND id_active='1'"));
    $res = mysql_fetch_array($qry);
?>
```

**Edit**

I have written but getting null value

my code:

```
$condition = array('OR'=>array('Message.from_id'=>1,'Message.to_id'=>8),'OR'=>array('Message.from_id'=>8,'Message.to_id'=>1),'Message.is_active'=>1);
$message=$this->Message->find("all",array('conditions'=>$condition));
pr($message);
```

Output:

```
array
(

)
```

Comment: Update your question with some sample input in `messages` and what you expect to see as output.

Comment: Which records should your sample query return? Because if I run your sample SQL, it returns nothing too. Your base SQL is perhaps wrong? None of your samples have a `to_id` of `from_id` of 1, so your sample reduces down to `from_id=8 AND to_id=8` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/faa1b0/2

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you would like to list the conversation try out this:

```
 $this->Message->find('all' ,
            array(
                'conditions'=>array(
                    'AND'=>array(
                        'OR'=>array(
                        array('AND'=>array('from_id'=>1, 'to_id'=>'8')),
                        array('AND'=>array('from_id'=>8, 'to_id'=>'1'))
                        ),
                        'is_active'=>1
                    )
                )
            )

        );
```

The good query is:

SELECT `Message`.`id`, `Message`.`from_id`, `Message`.`to_id`, `Message`.`is_active`, `Message`.`message` FROM `c23dev1`.`messagess` AS `Message` WHERE ((((((`from_id` = 1) AND (`to_id` = 8))) OR (((`from_id` = 8) AND (`to_id` = 1))))) AND (`is_active` = '1'))

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend using [Dogmatic69's converter](http://dogmatic69.com/sql-to-cakephp-find-converter). That gave this result for your query:

```
'conditions' => array(
    array(
        'or' => array(
            'from_id' => '8',
            'to_id' => '1',
        ),
    ),
    'id_active' => '1',
),
```

I'm not sure what your original SQL query is actually trying to return, but if you want all messages between user 7 and user 8, your query should be something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages 
WHERE ((from_id='7' AND to_id='8') OR (from_id='8' AND to_id='7'))
AND is_active='1';
```

Here's a [SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/faa1b0/6).

Comment: It is showing that record which `from_id=8` and `to_id=1` but i need also `from_id=1` and `to_id=8`

Comment: I don't understand. Your query specifically says to include "`from_id=8` and `to_id=1`".

Comment: So does that mean my examples now work? Basically, are you trying to show all messages between users 7 and 8, or all messages sent to/from user 7 and all messages to/from user 8, regardless of whether they were sent to each other?

Comment: Yes @Cylindric i want to show the conversation between each other.

Comment: Then your original SQL is wrong. Use my example from my Answer. That gives all messages "FROM A TO B" and all messages "FROM B TO A".